# Can I create my own UI project for C# Identity pages?

Tags: c#, architecture, single-sign-on, openiddict, microsoft-identity-web

First of all, this is more like an architecture and management question, I'm building a SSO Server with Microsoft Identity + OpenIdDict, but I wanted to create a separated react/nextjs front end for the SSO, since all our front end projects and code are in nextjs, making it easier for the team to manage the SSO UI.

Is it a great choice? Or due to security protocols should I really stick with the MVC front end?

I'm expecting some guidance to understand if I'm going to face security and architecture bad practices and what should I be concerned with.